# How to store users data permanently

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am currently doing a school project and I am in charge of making a forum from scratch. I was intending to create a "Add Section" button, which when clicked, creates a new question box. However I am not sure on how I should go about doing it.

What I am able to achieve so far, is to utilize the data the users pass on towards me, but I am unable to ensure that it stays on my code once the user has refresh. Is it a limitation of local storage? And if it is, any alternative in which I would be able to use?

Page 1 of my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Testing.css">
  <script>
  function addNew(){
  var datatwo = localStorage.datatwo;
  var newData = document.createTextNode(datatwo);
  var hello = document.createElement("th");
  hello.appendChild(newData);
  document.getElementById("Questions").appendChild(hello);
}
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="Addnew">
      <button onclick="addNew()" id ="AddNewButton">Add new </button>
    </div>
    <h1>This is Page 1 </h1>
    <table>
      <tr id="Questions">
        <th>What is my Name</th>
        <th>What is his name</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Justin</td>
        <td>James</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
        <nav>
            <div id="footerPages">

                  <ul>
                        <li><p>Page 1 of 3</p></li>
                        <li><a href=""> < Prev </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> 1 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="Testing2.html"> 2 </a></li>

                        <li><a href="#"> 3 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> 4 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> 5 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> 6 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> 7 </a></li>
                          <li><a href="Testing2.html"> Next ></a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>




  </body>

</html>
```

Page 2 of my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Testing.css">
  <script>
   function addNew(){
     var data = prompt("What is your question?");
     localStorage.datatwo = data;

   }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="Addnew">
      <button onclick="addNew()" id ="AddNewButton">Add new </button>
    </div>
    <h1>HI THIS IS PAGE 2</h1>
    <table>
      <tr id="Questions">
        <th>What is my Name</th>
        <th>What is his name</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Justin</td>
        <td>James</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
        <nav>
            <div id="footerPages">

                  <ul>
                        <li><p>Page 1 of 3</p></li>
                        <li><a href="Testing.html"> < Prev </a></li>
                        <li><a href="Testing.html"> 1 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> 2 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> 3 </a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"> Next ></a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>




  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your two pages of code are the same

Comment: Also you can adopt(choose) any ready use forum like cms for your project. (PHP BB)

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
localStorage.getItem(key, value);
```

Your code is not persistent because you are just setting some property to the object.

Answer (score 0):

> As you said you are currently doing a school project so i am not
>   blaming you for using plain javascript (without javascript framework) in your project. But you may use jQuery to make it easier.

LocalStorage is used to store the data locally (permanently for you).
SessionStorage is used to store the data per session/tab.

I think you want to update stored data to page 1. To do this change your script tag as

```
<script>
  function addNew(){
  var questionHead = document.createTextNode("Your Question");

  var queHeadElement = document.createElement("th");
  queHeadElement.appendChild(questionHead);
  document.getElementById("Questions").appendChild(queHeadElement);

  var datatwo = localStorage.datatwo;
  var newQuestionText = document.createTextNode(datatwo);
  var newQuestionTextElement = document.createElement("td");
  newQuestionTextElement.appendChild(newQuestionText);
  document.getElementById("myNewQuestion").appendChild(newQuestionTextElement);
}
  </script>
```

And change your table with this

```
<table>
  <tr id="Questions">
    <th>What is my Name</th>
    <th>What is his name</th>

  </tr>

  <tr id="myNewQuestion">
    <td>Justin</td>
    <td>James</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using this code, latest data from the localStorage will be displayed in the table with button click.

Above code will work fine. But i want to mention one more thing here.

> `<li><a href=""> < Prev </a></li>`

If you want to use less then or greater then symbols like < Prev browser will treat as if Prev is an html element. And browser will try to find its closing tag as <Prev/> or <Prev></Prev>. Although above code is working here but it should not be written in this way. You should always use `&lt;` for < symbol and `&gt;` for >

```
<li><a href=""> &gt; Prev </a></li>
```

I hope this answer will help you in your project. Best of luck for your project.